# Mixing different RAM voltages and speeds

Tags: memory, ddr3

I have 8 GB of [Kingston's DDR3 1333 MHz 1.5 V](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/KVR1333D3N9_2G.pdf) memory installed in my PC. Can I mix it with [Kingston's DDR3 1600 MHz 1.65 V](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/KHX1600C9D3B1K2_8GX.pdf) memory?

I have an Asus P8P67 Rev. 3.0 motherboard, am I able to overvoltage the 1.65 V memory to 1.5 V and drop down the speed to 1333 MHz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working good, no problems at all.